# Flutter - How to decrypt a RSA private key encrypted string if we have RSA public key with us?

Tags: android, flutter, encryption, dart, cryptography

Flutter app receives public key in the form of contents of public.pem file which would be a string like "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIICqq7DBi9sBXZfDYJC+G57JYUCAwEAAQ==
....
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----".
We also have a hashed string like "yBuHq6gZ...dgWs=".
Algorithm used to hash was RSA and following nodejs code was executed to generate the keys:

```
crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', 
    {
            modulusLength: modulusLength,
            namedCurve: 'secp256k1', 
            publicKeyEncoding: {
                type: 'spki',
                format: 'pem'     
            },     
            privateKeyEncoding: {
                type: 'pkcs8',
                format: 'pem',
                cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',
                passphrase: passphrase
            } 
    });
```

I wish to decrypt the hashed value. It was easy in nodejs by using the crypto library but I can't find how to do it in dart (Flutter).

Comment: Are you confused? as far as I know, Private key is used for signing and public key is used for encryption and then private key for decryption. Correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: There is probably a conceptual confusion here and it's not clear what you mean. What you're trying is the generation of a cryptographic key pair which uses the RSA public key cryptosystem. However, your code seems to be strange given that you're trying to pass some parameter for an ECDSA curve i.e. secp256k1. What exactly are you trying to do? Also RSA is not a hash function, Could you clarify what you are intending to do and what your use case is?

Answer (score 1):

This is my example. I hope that will be helpful.

```
dependencies:
   encrypt: ^5.0.1

import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/export.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

/// RSA decrypt by public key
/// PKCS1
String decryptByPublicKey(String public, String content) {
  RSAKeyParser parser = RSAKeyParser();
  RSAPublicKey publicKey = parser.parse(public) as RSAPublicKey;
  AsymmetricBlockCipher cipher = PKCS1Encoding(RSAEngine());
  cipher
    ..init(false, PublicKeyParameter<RSAPublicKey>(publicKey));
  return utf8.decode(cipher.process(Encrypted.fromBase64(content).bytes));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it was a misconception only. I needed both the key, original text and signature to verify the signature. I thought that with only key and signature I can get original text which is not possible.